# Unable to compile xelatex.fmt correctly

Tags: xetex, format-files, ini

When I launch `xetex --ini --etex xelatex.ini` to compile `xelatex.fmt` I get the following error:

```
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.ltx
File: preload.ltx 2014/09/29 v2.1g LaTeX Kernel (Font Preloading)
))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \UnicodeEncodingName 
                                
l.6994 ...{\textzerooldstyle} \UnicodeEncodingName
                                                  {\oldstylenums{0}}
```

I get this error 96 times. At the end, the format file is eventually created.

But then when I try to use this format file I get new errors:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TU+lmr on input line 112.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tulmr.fd
File: tulmr.fd 2017/01/26 v1.8 Standard LaTeX font definitions for Latin Modern

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> <-5.5>UnicodeFontFile 
                                 {lmroman5-regular}{UnicodeFontTeXLigatures ...
l.60    }{}
           
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I get that error 32 times and then starts a new type of errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> <->UnicodeFontFile 
                              {lmromancaps10-regular}{UnicodeFontTeXLigatures }
l.76 ...ps10-regular}{\UnicodeFontTeXLigatures}}{}
                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

and so on until the coup de grâce

```
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
```

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem in the format? I need to use my own patterns and therefore need to recompile the xelatex format file.

PS. Here is the complete log file of the format creation, before the error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (INITEX)  5 APR 2021 11:25
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**xelatex.ini
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/xelatex.ini (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg)
\openout15 = `texsys.aux'.


./texsys.aux found


\@currdir set to: ./.


Assuming \openin and \input 
have the same search path.


Defining UNIX/DOS style filename parser.

catcodes, registers,
\maxdimen=\dimen10
\hideskip=\skip10
\p@=\dimen11
\z@=\dimen12
\z@skip=\skip11
\voidb@x=\box10
 parameters,
\normalbaselineskip=\skip12
\normallineskip=\skip13
\normallineskiplimit=\dimen13
\interfootnotelinepenalty=\count23
\strutbox=\box11

LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.ltx (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count24
\l_tmpa_int=\count25
\l_tmpb_int=\count26
\g_tmpa_int=\count27
\g_tmpb_int=\count28
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count29
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count30
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count31
\c__ior_term_noprompt_ior=\count32
\c_log_iow=\count33
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count34
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count35
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count36
\l__iow_indent_int=\count37
\c_zero_dim=\dimen14
\c_max_dim=\dimen15
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen16
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen17
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen18
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen19
\c_zero_skip=\skip14
\c_max_skip=\skip15
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip16
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip17
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip18
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip19
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count38
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count39
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen20
\g__intarray_font_int=\count40
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count41
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count42
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count43
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count44
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count45
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count46
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count47
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count48
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count49
\g__fp_array_int=\count50
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count51
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count52
\l__sort_length_int=\count53
\l__sort_min_int=\count54
\l__sort_top_int=\count55
\l__sort_max_int=\count56
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count57
\l__sort_block_int=\count58
\l__sort_begin_int=\count59
\l__sort_end_int=\count60
\l__sort_A_int=\count61
\l__sort_B_int=\count62
\l__sort_C_int=\count63
\l__str_modulo_int=\count64
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count65
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count66
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count67
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count68
\l__tl_peek_charcode_int=\count69
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count70
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count71
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count72
\l__regex_balance_int=\count73
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count74
\l__regex_mode_int=\count75
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count76
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count77
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count78
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count79
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count80
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count81
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count82
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count83
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count84
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count85
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count86
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count87
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count88
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count89
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count90
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count91
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count92
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count93
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count94
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count95
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count96
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count97
\l__regex_last_char_success_int=\count98
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count99
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count100
\l__regex_step_int=\count101
\l__regex_min_thread_int=\count102
\l__regex_max_thread_int=\count103
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count104
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count105
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count106
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count107
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count108
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count109
\c_empty_box=\box12
\l_tmpa_box=\box13
\l_tmpb_box=\box14
\g_tmpa_box=\box15
\g_tmpb_box=\box16
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen21
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen22
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen23
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen24
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen25
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen26
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen27
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen28
\l__box_internal_box=\box17
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box18
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen29
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen30
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen31
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen32
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen33
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen34
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen35
\c_empty_coffin=\box19
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box20
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box21
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box22
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box23
\g_tmpa_coffin=\box24
\g_tmpb_coffin=\box25
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen36
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen37
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen38
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen39
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen40
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen41
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen42
\c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box26
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box27
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box28
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box29
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen43
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen44
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen45
\g__char_data_ior=\read0
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def
File: l3deprecation.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Deprecated functions
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.ltx (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse-generic.tex
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count110
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count111
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count112
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count113
)) hacks,
\l__hook_labels_int=\count114

LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \NewHook with sig. 'm' on line 2633.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \NewReversedHook with sig. 'm' on line 2634.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \NewMirroredHookPair with sig. 'mm' on line
(LaTeX3)     2635.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AddToHook with sig. 'mo+m' on line 2637.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \AddToHookNext with sig. 'm+m' on line 2639.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \RemoveFromHook with sig. 'mo' on line 2641.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \SetDefaultHookLabel with sig. 'm' on line 2687.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \DeclareDefaultHookLabel with sig. 'm' on line
(LaTeX3)     2701.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PushDefaultHookLabel with sig. 'm' on line
(LaTeX3)     2703.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \PopDefaultHookLabel with sig. '' on line 2705.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \DeclareHookRule with sig. 'mmmm' on line 2719.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \DeclareDefaultHookRule with sig. 'mmm' on line
(LaTeX3)     2721.


LaTeX3 Info: Defining command \ClearHookRule with sig. 'mmm' on line 2724.

\@tempcnta=\count115
\@tempcntb=\count116
\@tempdima=\dimen46
\@tempdimb=\dimen47
\@tempdimc=\dimen48
\@tempboxa=\box30
\@tempskipa=\skip20
\@tempskipb=\skip21
\@temptokena=\toks10
\@flushglue=\skip22
 control, par, spacing,
\@savsk=\dimen49
\@savsf=\count117
\smallskipamount=\skip23
\medskipamount=\skip24
\bigskipamount=\skip25
\fill=\skip26
 files,
\@inputcheck=\read1
\@unused=\write0
\@mainaux=\write1
\@partaux=\write2
\@clubpenalty=\count118
LaTeX Info: Redefining \IfFileExists on input line 3467.
 font encodings, lengths,
\everymath=\toks11
\everydisplay=\toks12
\series@check@toks=\toks13
\every@math@size=\toks14
\lower@bound=\dimen50
\upper@bound=\dimen51
\c@mv@normal=\count119
\c@mv@bold=\count120

====================================

Local config file fonttext.cfg used

====================================
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/fonttext.cfg
File: fonttext.cfg 1997/08/20 CSLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlenc.def
File: omlenc.def 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX file
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX file
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.def
File: ot1enc.def 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX file
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2enc.def
File: il2enc.def 1997/08/20 CSLaTeX
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.def
File: omsenc.def 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX file
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd
File: t1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmr.fd
File: ot1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2cmr.fd
File: il2cmr.fd 1997/02/06 CSLaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmss.fd
File: ot1cmss.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1cmtt.fd
File: ot1cmtt.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
))
====================================

Local config file fontmath.cfg used

====================================
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.cfg
File: fontmath.cfg 2020/08/01 v3.0i LaTeX Kernel (Uncustomised math font setup)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontmath.ltx
File: fontmath.ltx 2020/08/01 v3.0i LaTeX Kernel (Math font setup)

=== Don't modify this file, use a .cfg file instead ===

LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 44.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 45.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmm.fd
File: omlcmm.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmsy.fd
File: omscmsy.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omxcmex.fd
File: omxcmex.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ucmr.fd
File: ucmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
\symoperators=\mathgroup0
\symletters=\mathgroup1
\symsymbols=\mathgroup2
\symlargesymbols=\mathgroup3
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 63.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/cmm/b/it on input line 64.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/cmsy/b/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/cmss/bx/n on input line 73.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/cmr/bx/it on input line 74.
))
====================================

Local config file preload.cfg used

=====================================
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.cfg
File: preload.cfg 2020/08/01 v3.0i LaTeX Kernel (Uncustomised preload font setup)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/preload.ltx
File: preload.ltx 2014/09/29 v2.1g LaTeX Kernel (Font Preloading)
))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \UnicodeEncodingName 
                                
l.6994 ...{\textzerooldstyle} \UnicodeEncodingName
                                                  {\oldstylenums{0}}
```

Comment: compiles fine for me. What does the log (of the format creation) say before the error?

Comment: Not knowing how to post a file on stackoverflow I added the code to my query. Thanks in advance Ulrike!

Comment: your xetex finds a file from cslatex: `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/fonttext.cfg` and then things go wrong.

Comment: did you set TEXINPUTS?

Comment: Thank you so much Ulrike, *Heilige Protektorin der TeX-Verunglückten* !! I ran it again and it used `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fonttext.cfg`. Just a question: this is obviously a bug in texlive isn't it?

Comment: I mean: if instead of reading some texlive/2020 file it reads some other texlive/2020 file, this cannot be due to interference by my personal files? Alphabetically cslatex comes before latex, and therefore the wrong file is read. But how come it doesn't happen on your machine?

Comment: did you set texinputs?

Comment: My TEXINPUT specific to xe* looks like this: `TEXINPUTS.xelatex       = .;$TEXMF/tex/{xelatex,latex,xetex,generic,}//;$HOMETEXMF
TEXINPUTS.xeplain       = .;$TEXMF/tex/{xeplain,eplain,plain,xetex,generic,}//;$HOMETEXMF
TEXINPUTS.xetex         = .;$TEXMF/tex/{xetex,plain,generic,}//;$HOMETEXMF
`